# undo file deletes made by dropbox seelctive sync

Tags: dropbox

I have some files that i placed inside a folder that is not sync'ed with dropbox. but when i tried to sync that folder, thinking that the copies on the server will be sync'ed were deleted.
How do i do this? anyway to recover those files?

also [Dropbox "reverse"-selective sync](https://superuser.com/questions/430768/dropbox-reverse-selective-sync)  as what is said there, one of the answers is to transfer the file outside dropbox folder then sync that folder  and copy the transferred files again -- which is what i should have done but damaged done how do i recover those files? also there are no files inside the trashbin

Thanks for your time